# Como concatenar variáveis num template do Django

Tags: django

Tenho um templete do Django que recebe dados de uma tabela para exibir a lista na tela, conforme abaixo:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for item in itens_lista %}
        <div class="post">
            <h1><a href="">{{ item.DESCR_ITEM}}</a></h1>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Para cada item lido é gerado um link que abre a edição do item, porém, além da descrição (`item.DESCR_ITEM`) do item eu gostaria de exibir também o código (`item.COD_ITEM`).

Hoje exibe assim:

- Celular
- Notebook
- Pendrive

Eu gostaria que ficasse assim:

- 001 - Celular
- 002 - Notebook
- 003 - Pendrive

Antecipadamente agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: O código não ficou correto quando eu colei. Onde aparece {{ item.DESCR_ITEM}} na verdade é um link html cujo rótulo é este. Eu quero que este rótulo concatene COD_ITEM + DESCR_ITEM

Comment: Testou a minha resposta?

Comment: Acabei de testar. Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Coloquei o aceite. Mais uma vez obrigado.

Comment: Legal, É interessante sempre colocar o aceite quando alguem responde, dessa forma vc e o autor da resposta ganham pontos. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize o filtro `add`:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for item in itens_lista %}
        <div class="post">
            <h1><a href="">{{item.COD_ITEM | add:" - " | add:item.DESCR_ITEM}}</a></h1>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```